# How to find tags with certain children attributes? - BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and BeautifulSoup, how would I search certain tags whose children have certain attributes?
For example,

```
<section ...>
<a href="URL" ...>
<h4 itemprop="name">ABC</h4>
<p class="open"></p>
</a>
</section>
```

I hope if I could get all names ('ABC') and urls("URL") if class="open". I can get all sections by

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name="section")
```

But I don't know how to add other conditions since tag.children is a listiterator.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're looking for certain attributes with the `<p>` tags, I would search for only `<p>` tags with `attrs={"class": "open"}` and then select the parent (which is the `<a>` tag) and gather the rest of the information from that.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
items = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class": "open"})
for item in items:
    name = item.parent.h4.text
    url = item.parent.attrs.get('href', None)
    print("{} : {}".format(name, url))
```